# Django - customizing the add view of the admin page

Tags: django

Let's say I have a data model for a Pen. Pens can be made of either metal or wood.
Metal pens can be silver or white
Wooden pens can be blue or green.
so there must be no metal pen in blue.

Is there a way to replace the material selection in the add button to display a combination of material name/color?
I think there must be a trick with the fieldsets.

```
# model.py
from django.db import models
class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.color

class Material(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    color = models.OneToOneField(Color)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s_%s" % (str(self.color), self.type)

class Pen(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s_%s" % (str(self.material), self.label)

# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Material, Color, Pen

class PenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('label', 'material', 'get_color',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('label', 'material')
        }),
    )
    def get_color(self, obj):
        return obj.material.color
    get_color.short_description = 'Color'

admin.site.register(Pen, PenAdmin)
admin.site.register(Material)
admin.site.register(Color)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not using the fieldsets. I think that is meant for very simple alterations.
Here are the steps to accomplish it:

1. override the url for the add:

   ```
   url(r'^admin/penshop/pen/add/$', 'penshop.views.add_pen'),
   url(r'^admin/save_pen/$', 'penshop.views.save_pen'),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   ```
2. make a add_pen.html template which has your custom page. Make sure the form contains `{% csrf_token %}`
3. add an entry point to your views.py to handle the form request:

   ```
   @staff_member_required
   def save_pen(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
           values = request.META.items()
           label = request.POST.get("label", "")
           color = request.POST.get("color", "")
           material = request.POST.get("material", "")
           if len(label) > 0 and len(color) > 0 and len(material) > 0 and\
               not color.startswith('-') and not material.startswith('-'):
               import pdb;pdb.set_trace
               col_obj = Color.objects.filter(color=color)[0]
               mat_obj = Material.objects.filter(type=material, color=col_obj)[0]
               pen_obj = Pen(label=label, material=mat_obj)
               pen_obj.save()
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/penshop/pen/')
           else:
               raise Exception('Bad data. It is not going to be saved!')
       else:
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')

       return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
   ```